# Firebase - are credential objects one time use only?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, credentials

I have logged into firebase Phone provider successfully and have saved a credential (lets call it credential A ) object for that Phone identify provider.
                       Now my question is about reusing this credential.

If I delete  (or sign out ) the phone provider account and log-in with another provider (Say Google)  am I able to link the 
                   Credential A to google afterwards ?  When I tried on ios the following error is occurred:

[image]

**Once I use a credential to login am I not able to reuse it? This is my question ?**

Comment: can you add your code please?

Comment: just use any credential to log into firebase and try to use it again, seems you cant .can you verify.

Comment: 1) are you talking about just any credentials or phone provider only? & are you talking about the, credentials object that comes with firebase user?

Comment: Question is about any. But not sure if it's only for phone.

Comment: i wonder if since phone provider is OTP (one time password) maybe it only works once but other credentials can be reused. i want to find out

Comment: credential linking works well in firebase. we use it everyday. OTP is one time thing, but after you signed up using it that account should be there. you can't use the same OTP code again. if that's what you r asking. once user signed in firebase doen't end that session until you explicitly sign out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a summary on different credentials and their reusability.

1. Email/password credentials are reusable.
2. OAuth credentials (Google, Facebook, etc) are reusable but expire after some time depending on the underlying OAuth access token or ID token expiration.
3. Email link credentials are not reusable.
4. Phone auth credentials are not reusable.

Comment: Can you give an example of #3

Comment: `var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink(email, window.location.href);` This credential is only usable once.